# Most efficient way to add two CSR sparse matrices with the same sparsity pattern in python

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am using sparse matrices in python, namely

```
scipy.sparse.csr_matrix
```

I am in principle free to choose the exact sparse implementation, as long as the matrices support matrix-vector multiplication and addition/subtraction of matrices with the same sparsity pattern. Currently, at every time step, I construct a new sparse matrix from scratch and add it to the existing matrix. I believe that my code could be unnecessarily losing time due to

- Construction time of sparse matrix
- Addition of the sparse matrices, assuming that the underlying algorithm inside CSR matrix implementation has to find matching sparse entries before adding them up.

My guess would be that the sparse matrix is internally stored as a numpy array of values + a few index arrays denoting where those values are located. The question is if it is possible to directly add the underlying value arrays without touching the sparsity structure. Is something like this possible?

```
new_values = np.linspace(0, num_values)
csr_mat.val += new_values
```

Comment: First of all, you should profile your code (`ipython` has `prun` and `lprun` specifically for this) to make sure that the bottlenecks are where you think they are. Second of all, is there any reason to not just keep an array of values that updates and create a new matrix each step. Something like `values += np.linspace(0, num_values); new_mat = csr_matrix(data, indices, indptr);`? This would spare the index matching in the matrix add.

Comment: I have profiled my code, and I can see where the bottlenecks are :) Creating a matrix is time-expensive, so if it can be skipped it would be great. I have tried a hand-written matrix-multiplication by simply looping over the index list and += individual multiplications to the resulting vector, but, as expected, it performs much worse than CSR matrix-vector multiplication, because the latter likely uses vectorized and parallel acceleration for such simple operations

Comment: Make a small matrix and look at the key attributes, `.data`, `.indices`, `.intptr`.  The data values can be changed without changing sparsity.

Comment: Setting mat.data = newdata does the job. Thanks @hpaulj . If you wish, you can write as a solution, I will accept